# How can I find the two positions with the two highest numbers in a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript

I'm working in a JavaScript project where in this case I am trying to get the two arrays with the biggest value in position 2.

```
[-20.172, 35.251, 0],
[-16.368, 21.792, 26.81],
[-29.311, 18.393, 0],
[14.54, 15.23, 0],
[-1.61, 12.91, 27.692],
[0, 0, 0]
```

the intended answer should be like this:

```
[-16.368, 21.792, 26.81],
[-1.61, 12.91, 27.692]
```

I can't sort by the ones that have a zero and the ones who doesn't have it, some other cases in the project I'm working could possibly have different numbers on the position 2.

any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean with zeros? what have you tried? btw, why not sorting?

Comment: Use `sort()` with a comparison function that compares index 2 of the elements.

Comment: @Barmar, there's not a chance in .... that he will be able to figure out the compare function

Comment: @DCR OK, I closed it as a duplicate of a question that shows how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const arr = [
  [-20.172, 35.251, 0],
  [-16.368, 21.792, 26.81],
  [-29.311, 18.393, 0],
  [14.54, 15.23, 0],
  [-1.61, 12.91, 27.692],
  [0, 0, 0]
];

const [max1Index, max2Index] = arr.reduce(([max1Index, max2Index], { 2: num }, index) => {
  const max1 = arr[max1Index][2], max2 = arr[max2Index][2];
  return num > max1
    ? [index, max1Index]
    : num > max2
      ? [max1Index, index]
      : [max1Index, max2Index];
}, [0, 0]);

console.log(arr[max1Index], arr[max2Index]);
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! thank you very much!, I knew it was with reduce but I didn't figured out the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't sort by the ones that have a zero

Could it be the array is declared `const`?

---

[Array.Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

[Array.Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

- sorts, in place, descending
- returns an array of (copies of) first 2 elements

```js
    var topTwo = function ( array_of_arrays ) {
      return array_of_arrays.sort((a, b) => b[2] - a[2])
                            .slice(0, 2) ;
    };

    var arr = [
      [-20.172, 35.251, 7],
      [-16.368, 21.792, 26.81],
      [-29.311, 18.393, 0],
      [14.54, 15.23, 0],
      [-1.61, 12.91, 27.692],
      [0, 0, -3]
    ];
    console.log( topTwo(arr) );
```